# Creating a calendar event from cell data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got my bit of code that allows me to enter a date and time and it will create a calendar event.  The only problem is the date and time have to be entered in a cell that is formatted Date/Time.  If I take the date from one cell and the time from another and try to create a string using these I get an error that the "calendar.createEvent" doesn't work with strings.

How do I turn my string into a date and time?

```
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("xxxxxxx");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var datesheet = ss.getSheetByName("Schedule Job")
  var start = datesheet.getRange("C19").getValue() & " " & datesheet.getRange("C20").getValue();
  var end = datesheet.getRange("C30").getValue();

calendar.createEvent("Test",start,end);
```

Comment: Kindly share a sample spreadsheet or screenshot of data in your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating a string with them, try just adding them.

With a Date in A1 and a time in B1 put this formula in a cell:

```
=A1+B1
```

and then select the cell and choose Format>Number>DateTime

run your script off that value.